# How to extract a value from the gui in python?

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to print that value (9%) on the commandline. How can I identify the progressbar's objectname?

[image: pic]

Comment: maybe this helps you... https://devtalk.blender.org/t/how-to-get-progres-info-from-ops-object-bake/9628/4